# Как перезапускать import?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, python-import

У меня есть одна функция в которую вписано 3 импорта.
Они выполняются, но при повторном вызове функции они пропускаются.
Пробовал делать функцию в функции (эту внутрь основной):

```
def imp1(x):
    if x==1:   #через while тоже, с добавлением break
        import proj1
    return 
imp1(1)
```

Как можно перезапускать отдельные файлы.py которые лежат в этой же папке? Помогите пожалуйста! Не хватает только этого что бы закончить :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пожалуйста, не надо использовать импорт ТАК, у меня от этого глаза кровоточат.

Правильный подход:

1. В тех файлах, из которых нужно запускать логику, заворачиваете её в функцию.
2. В основном файле импортируете из этих файлов эти функции.
3. Запускаете эти функции в любых местах основного файла столько раз, сколько вам будет угодно.
4. PROFIT !!!

Импорт не предназначен для того, чтобы однократно выполнить содержимое других файлов. Он предназначен для того, чтобы импортировать из другого файла какие-то объекты, и уже после этого с ними работать.

В большинстве случаев все импорты следует делать в самом начале файла. Если вам начинает казаться, что вам необходимо сделать импорт в середине файла, то в 90% случаев это означает, что вы делаете что-то не правильно.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 4):

`from importlib import reload` вам в помощь.

Из  документации https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload

Перезагрузите ранее импортированный модуль. 
Аргумент должен быть объектом модуля, поэтому он должен быть успешно импортирован ранее. 
Это полезно, если вы отредактировали исходный файл модуля с помощью внешнего редактора 
и хотите опробовать новую версию, не выходя из интерпретатора Python...

```
from importlib import reload
import proj1

# Делайте изменения в модуле proj1.py

# Перезагрузите ранее импортированный модуль.
proj1 = reload(proj1)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.